# Alfresco integration with drupal

Tags: drupal, alfresco

I am integarting my drupal website with alfresco. Here is my settings.php code:

```
$conf['cmis_repositories'] = array( 'default' => array( 'user' => 'admin', 'password' => 'admin', 'url' => 'http://localhost:8443/alfresco/s/cmis' ) )
```

---

Everyting connecting fine but while creating view through CMIS view and displaying it in drupal block its giving me below error:

```
HTTP call to [http://localhost:8443/alfresco/s/cmis/queries] returned [500]. Response: Web Script Status 500 - Internal Error Web Script Status 500 - Internal Error The Web Script /alfresco/s/cmis/queries has responded with a status of 500 - Internal Error. 500 Description: An error inside the HTTP server which prevented it from fulfilling the request. &nbsp; Message:09050002 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 09050029 Failed to execute script 'classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/cmis/queries.post.cmisquery.js': 09050028 &nbsp; Exception:java.io.EOFException - SSL peer shut down incorrectly &nbsp; com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:333) com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:830) com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1170) com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:637) com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:89) java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65) java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:123) org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod.writeRequestBody(EntityEnclosingMethod.java:506) org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2114) org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1096) org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398) org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171) org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397) org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323) org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrQueryHTTPClient.executeQuery(SolrQueryHTTPClient.java:344) org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrQueryLanguage.executeQuery(SolrQueryLanguage.java:49) org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrCMISQueryServiceImpl.query(SolrCMISQueryServiceImpl.java:93) sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.SubsystemProxyFactory$1.invoke(SubsystemProxyFactory.java:65) org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202) $Proxy157.query(Unknown Source) org.alfresco.repo.cmis.rest.CMISScript.query(CMISScript.java:683) sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:155) org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:243) org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:76) org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c2._c0(file:/C:/Alfresco/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/cmis/queries.post.cmisquery.js:67) org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c2.call(file:/C:/Alfresco/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/cmis/queries.post.cmisquery.js) org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:393) org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2834) org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c2.call(file:/C:/Alfresco/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/cmis/queries.post.cmisquery.js) org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c2.exec(file:/C:/Alfresco/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/cmis/queries.post.cmisquery.js) org.alfresco.repo.jscript.RhinoScriptProcessor.executeScriptImpl(RhinoScriptProcessor.java:492) org.alfresco.repo.jscript.RhinoScriptProcessor.execute(RhinoScriptProcessor.java:198) org.alfresco.repo.processor.ScriptServiceImpl.execute(ScriptServiceImpl.java:212) org.alfresco.repo.processor.ScriptServiceImpl.executeScript(ScriptServiceImpl.java:174) org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryScriptProcessor.executeScript(RepositoryScriptProcessor.java:102) org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractWebScript.executeScript(AbstractWebScript.java:1285) org.alfresco.repo.cmis.rest.CMISWebScript.executeScript(CMISWebScript.java:46) org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeWebScript.execute(DeclarativeWebScript.java:86) org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer$2.execute(RepositoryContainer.java:407) org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:388) org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecute(RepositoryContainer.java:476) org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecuteAs(RepositoryContainer.java:514) org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.executeScript(RepositoryContainer.java:330) org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:377) org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:209) org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.servlet.WebScriptServlet.service(WebScriptServlet.java:118) javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.GlobalLocalizationFilter.doFilter(GlobalLocalizationFilter.java:58) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233) org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191) org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:470) org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127) org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293) org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:877) org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:594) org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1675) java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) &nbsp; Exception:javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException - Remote host closed connection during handshake &nbsp; com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:849) &nbsp; Exception:org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.lucene.LuceneQueryParserException - 09050028 &nbsp; org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrQueryHTTPClient.executeQuery(SolrQueryHTTPClient.java:390) &nbsp; Exception:org.alfresco.scripts.ScriptException - 09050029 Failed to execute script 'classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/cmis/queries.post.cmisquery.js': 09050028 &nbsp; org.alfresco.repo.jscript.RhinoScriptProcessor.execute(RhinoScriptProcessor.java:202) &nbsp; Exception:org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.WebScriptException - 09050002 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 09050029 Failed to execute script 'classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/cmis/queries.post.cmisquery.js': 09050028 &nbsp; org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractWebScript.createStatusException(AbstractWebScript.java:1047) &nbsp; Server:Enterprise v4.1.0 (143) schema 5,100 Time:Oct 5, 2012 10:59:44 AM &nbsp; Diagnostics:Inspect Web Script (org/alfresco/cmis/queries.post)
Error.
```

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You've specified `http` but a port that does SSL, hence the SSL error

You'll either want to change your URL to be `https://localhost:8443/` (note the s in https), or if you really want to use only http then use the http port so `http://localhost:8080/`

The Alfresco tomcat will generally list for http on port 8080, and https on 8443, but you can't mix and match the ports and protocols!